# Shortest way to check if params[:x][:y] exists

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to check if `params[:search][:city]` exists but this is what i get:

```
do_magic if params[:search].try(:city) # undefined method `city' for {"city"=>["3"]}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

This error shows up if the key exists, but it surprisingly works when the key doesn't exist.

Keep in mind that both `:search` and `:city` might not exist in the params hash at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try` is trying to call a method with a given name. You need a `[]` method, with a parameter.

```
do_magic if params[:search].try(:[], :city)
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, Just to make sure, Am i even approaching this the right way?

Comment: Yes, I would do it the same way

Answer (score 0):

**Sergio's** solution doesn't consider situation, when `:params[:search]` is a `String`. If so, ruby produces an error:

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

So the correct solution which covers all the cases is to check that `params[:search]` is a `Hash` and then check for the `:city` key.

```
do_magic if params[:search].is_a?(Hash) && params[:search][:city]
```

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that `params[:search]` comes from an html form. And it's either hash or nil. I can't imagine a form that can produce a hash **or** a string.

Comment: Jeff's question is incomplete — there is nothing about context. I faced this problem in controller action. When request will be similar to this `url.html?search=123`, `params[:search]` will return a `String`. Of course, everything is ok when `params[:search]` is `nil` or `Hash`